# How to get the statement correct using generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

SO I am using ExecutorService and wanted to generate Callables so that I can execute them using invokeAll

The Callables have different return type. Which made me think I can get done using wild card

```
Set<Callable<?>> executedCallables = new HashSet<Callable<?>>();
executedCallables.add(serviceHelper.getOwnerDetails()); --> returns Callable<OwnerDetails>
executedCallables.add(iqmServiceHelper.getUserDetails()); --> returns Callable<UserDetails>
```

in similar fashion I added statement for invokeAll

```
List<Future<? extends Object>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(executedCallables);
```

ad this gives me compiler error `The method invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Callable<?>>)` which I am not getting how to resolve.

Can someone please point out the error in usage and correct usage.

Just a heads up the compiler error is from JDK 6. And I do not think is going to be different in higher version JDK

PS :- There is a similar StackOverflow thread as well on this  [Collection of Callable and Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781299/collection-of-callable-and-generics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the signature of invokeAll is a bit too restrictive. It should be `Collection<? extends Callable<? extends T>>`, since the T is a producer here (remember from Effective Java: PECS - Producer Extends Consumer Super).
However we of course cannot change a JDK method here, so we have to live with it. Solution is to pass in a `Set<Callable<Object>`> and either use an unsafe cast (which is safe, since you are only extracting values of type T out of the Callable) or to use a method reference:

```
Set<Callable<Object>> callables = new HashSet<>();
callables.add((Callable) serviceHelper.getOwnerDetails()); // method one
callables.add(iqmServiceHelper.getUserDetails()::call); // method two
```

The final statement will look like below

```
try {
    List<Future<Object>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(executedCallables);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Above statement construct being fine I still do not get how to rectify the final statement List<Future<? extends Object>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(executedCallables);

Comment: You won't get out a `List<Future<? extends Object>>`, you will get a `List<Future<Object>>`.
There is no way to make the `T` a wildcard here.

Comment: This compiles fine for me:

    `Callable<String> foo = () -> "";
    Set<Callable<Object>> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(foo::call);
    ExecutorService service = null; // put something proper here
    List<Future<Object>> futures = service.invokeAll(set);`

Comment: I realized I was not checking the final error is for unhandled exception. Already marked this as correct solution

Comment: It's always the little things :D