# Java wildcard generic as return warning in Eclipse and SonarQube

Tags: java, generics, return, sonarqube

```
private List gridModel;

public List getGridModel() {
        return gridModel;
}
```

Eclipse shows a warning:

> List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized.

Changing the code to below will remove the warning

```
private List<?> gridModel;

public List<?> getGridModel() {
        return gridModel;
}
```

However the above code shows a Major pitfall error in SonarQube which says:

> Remove usage of generic wildcard type. Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters

So how can I fix this warning?
I see a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815023/generic-wildcard-types-should-not-be-used-in-return-parameters) but could not find the solution .

Using `Class<? extends Object>` did not remove Sonar warning.

Comment: Just curios as to why can't you use a type parameter for the `getGridModel` method or use a type parameter for the `class` that has the `gridModel`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So how can I fix this warning ?

You can use a type parameter for your class :

```
public class GridModelHolder<T> {
   private List<T>  gridModel;

   public List<T> getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
   }
}
```

The client code can then decide what type of `List` `GridModelHolder` holds :

`GridModelHolder<String> gridModelHolder = new GridModelHolder<String>(new ArrayList<String>);`

However, if you insist on using raw types, you can either suppress the warnings or simply have a List of objects (Neither of these are recommended)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class GridModelHolder {
   private List  gridModel;

   public List getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
   }
}
```

**OR**

```
public class GridModelHolder {
   private List<Object>  gridModel;

   public List<Object> getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make the class take a generic. Apply that generic to the `List`. Also, the warning is valid (a collection type without a generic is a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)). Something like,

```
class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> gridModel;    
    public List<T> getGridModel() {
            return gridModel;
    }
}
```

If you really want to disable the type-checking then make the `List` generic on `Object` (which is what a raw type is) like

```
private List<Object> gridModel;    
public List<Object> getGridModel() {
        return gridModel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense; there's nothing wrong with returning `Foo<?>` if the API needs to. Even the `Object` class has a 
[method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) 
like that.

Here's the list of public methods in JDK that return with wildcards:

(There are more in `javax`, but the list is too long to be posted on stackoverflow. See [complete list](https://gist.github.com/zhong-j-yu/b6f993424ccea2107f15) )

```
java.awt.Font#getAttributes -> java.util.Map<java.awt.font.TextAttribute, ?>
java.awt.Toolkit#mapInputMethodHighlight -> java.util.Map<java.awt.font.TextAttribute, ?>
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor#getDefaultRepresentationClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor#getRepresentationClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.awt.im.InputMethodHighlight#getStyle -> java.util.Map<java.awt.font.TextAttribute, ?>
java.beans.BeanDescriptor#getBeanClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.beans.BeanDescriptor#getCustomizerClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.beans.EventSetDescriptor#getListenerType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor#getIndexedPropertyType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor#getPropertyEditorClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.beans.PropertyDescriptor#getPropertyType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.io.ObjectStreamClass#forClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.io.ObjectStreamField#getType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.Class#asSubclass -> java.lang.Class<? extends U>
java.lang.Class#forName -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.Class#getComponentType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.Class#getDeclaringClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.Class#getEnclosingClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.Class#getEnclosingConstructor -> java.lang.reflect.Constructor<?>
java.lang.Class#getSuperclass -> java.lang.Class<? super T>
java.lang.ClassLoader#loadClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException#enumType -> java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.Enum>
java.lang.Object#getClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.annotation.Annotation#annotationType -> java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>
java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException#annotationType -> java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>
java.lang.annotation.Repeatable#value -> java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>
java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition#getDefinitionClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleInfo#getDeclaringClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleProxies#wrapperInstanceType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup#lookupClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.invoke.MethodType#parameterType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.invoke.MethodType#returnType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue#poll -> java.lang.ref.Reference<? extends T>
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue#remove -> java.lang.ref.Reference<? extends T>
java.lang.reflect.Executable#getDeclaringClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Field#getDeclaringClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Field#getType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Member#getDeclaringClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Method#getDeclaringClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Method#getReturnType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Parameter#getType -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.lang.reflect.Proxy#getProxyClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.rmi.activation.ActivationDesc#getData -> java.rmi.MarshalledObject<?>
java.rmi.activation.ActivationGroupDesc#getData -> java.rmi.MarshalledObject<?>
java.rmi.activation.ActivationInstantiator#newInstance -> java.rmi.MarshalledObject<? extends java.rmi.Remote>
java.rmi.activation.Activator#activate -> java.rmi.MarshalledObject<? extends java.rmi.Remote>
java.rmi.server.LoaderHandler#loadClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader#loadClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader#loadProxyClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi#loadClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi#loadProxyClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.security.acl.Group#members -> java.util.Enumeration<? extends java.security.Principal>
java.security.cert.CertPath#getCertificates -> java.util.List<? extends java.security.cert.Certificate>
java.security.cert.CertStore#getCRLs -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.CRL>
java.security.cert.CertStore#getCertificates -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.Certificate>
java.security.cert.CertStoreSpi#engineGetCRLs -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.CRL>
java.security.cert.CertStoreSpi#engineGetCertificates -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.Certificate>
java.security.cert.CertificateFactory#generateCRLs -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.CRL>
java.security.cert.CertificateFactory#generateCertificates -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.Certificate>
java.security.cert.CertificateFactorySpi#engineGenerateCRLs -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.CRL>
java.security.cert.CertificateFactorySpi#engineGenerateCertificates -> java.util.Collection<? extends java.security.cert.Certificate>
java.security.cert.CollectionCertStoreParameters#getCollection -> java.util.Collection<?>
java.security.cert.PolicyNode#getChildren -> java.util.Iterator<? extends java.security.cert.PolicyNode>
java.security.cert.PolicyNode#getPolicyQualifiers -> java.util.Set<? extends java.security.cert.PolicyQualifierInfo>
java.security.cert.X509CRL#getRevokedCertificates -> java.util.Set<? extends java.security.cert.X509CRLEntry>
java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate#atTime -> java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime<?>
java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime#from -> java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime<?>
java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime#from -> java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime<?>
java.time.chrono.Chronology#localDateTime -> java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime<? extends java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate>
java.time.chrono.Chronology#zonedDateTime -> java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime<? extends java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate>
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException#getArgumentClass -> java.lang.Class<?>
java.util.PriorityQueue#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super E>
java.util.Properties#propertyNames -> java.util.Enumeration<?>
java.util.SortedMap#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super K>
java.util.SortedSet#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super E>
java.util.Spliterator#getComparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super T>
java.util.TreeMap#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super K>
java.util.TreeSet#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super E>
java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService#submit -> java.util.concurrent.Future<?>
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super K>
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super E>
java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter#firstComplete -> java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter<?>
java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter#getCompleter -> java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter<?>
java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter#getRoot -> java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter<?>
java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter#nextComplete -> java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter<?>
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#submit -> java.util.concurrent.Future<?>
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool#submit -> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask<?>
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask#adapt -> java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask<?>
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue#comparator -> java.util.Comparator<? super E>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService#schedule -> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<?>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate -> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<?>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay -> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<?>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#schedule -> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<?>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleAtFixedRate -> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<?>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleWithFixedDelay -> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture<?>
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#submit -> java.util.concurrent.Future<?>
java.util.stream.Collectors#averagingDouble -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Double>
java.util.stream.Collectors#averagingInt -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Double>
java.util.stream.Collectors#averagingLong -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Double>
java.util.stream.Collectors#counting -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Long>
java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, M>
java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Map<K, D>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Map<K, java.util.List<T>>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingByConcurrent -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, M>
java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingByConcurrent -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<K, D>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingByConcurrent -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<K, java.util.List<T>>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#joining -> java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.CharSequence, ?, java.lang.String>
java.util.stream.Collectors#mapping -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, R>
java.util.stream.Collectors#maxBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Optional<T>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#minBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Optional<T>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#partitioningBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Map<java.lang.Boolean, D>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#partitioningBy -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Map<java.lang.Boolean, java.util.List<T>>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#reducing -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, T>
java.util.stream.Collectors#reducing -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, U>
java.util.stream.Collectors#reducing -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Optional<T>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#summarizingDouble -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics>
java.util.stream.Collectors#summarizingInt -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.IntSummaryStatistics>
java.util.stream.Collectors#summarizingLong -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.LongSummaryStatistics>
java.util.stream.Collectors#summingDouble -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Double>
java.util.stream.Collectors#summingInt -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Integer>
java.util.stream.Collectors#summingLong -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.lang.Long>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toCollection -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, C>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toConcurrentMap -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, M>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toConcurrentMap -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<K, U>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toList -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.List<T>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toMap -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, M>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toMap -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Map<K, U>>
java.util.stream.Collectors#toSet -> java.util.stream.Collector<T, ?, java.util.Set<T>>
java.util.zip.ZipFile#entries -> java.util.Enumeration<? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry>
java.util.zip.ZipFile#stream -> java.util.stream.Stream<? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry>
```

Comment: What's the point of a List if you can't add or get elements from it? Also, the reason why getClass uses an unbounded wildcard is because most of the methods in `Class` don't really need the type information to do their job.

Comment: you can get elements from a `List<?>`.

Comment: Surely you can. But you are missing the point. In this particular question, what's the point if the `List` can hold only `null` values?

Comment: Some SonarQube rules really are strange. This is one of them. If people are forced to write more complex code as a workaround(!) to make SonarCube happy (such as the `GridModelHolder` from @CKing) then something really is going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @JonnyDee The rule in `GridModelHokder` is not at all complex. A `List` without a type parameter can hold objects of any type, thus exposing the code to all sorts of exceptions or requiring programmers to resort to type casting and `instanceof` checks. One of the motivation behind introducing Generics in Java was type safety. Stating that this rule is useless is equivalent to saying that generics are useless IMO. Next, returning a `List` with a wildcard parameter can be problematic in some cases. Do read about "wildcard capturing" to see what I mean. Rarely would you need a wildcard List IMO.

Comment: @CKing "Rarely would you need a wildcard List". Maybe rarely, but definitely sometimes. That's the point. I like and appreciate type safety myself but sometimes you need to be able to give it up.

Comment: @JonnyDee For a few rare cases that you would want to use a `List<?>`, you want SonarQube to eliminate this rule? Isn't suppressing or ignoring the warnings a more logical thing to do when you know what you are doing? Aren't there more chances of developers not using `Collections` correctly and running into `ClassCastException` than developers using wildcard lists correctly? Think about it.

Comment: @CKing "Isn't suppressing or ignoring the warnings a more logical thing to do when you know what you are doing?" You're right. In out company this isn't allowed, however. But yes, I'm with you.