# Using generic wildcard types in return parameters

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Using generic wildcard types in return parameters in Java is generally discouraged. For example Effective Java, Item 28 states:

> **Do not use wildcard types as return types.** Rather than providing additional flexibility for your users, it would force them to use wildcard types in client code.
>
> Properly used, wildcard types are nearly invisible to users of a class. They cause methods to accept the parameters they should accept and reject those they should reject. **If the user of a class has to think about wildcard types, there is probably something wrong with the class’s API.**

However in certain cases it appears to be the most optimal choice, such as in code below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Container
{
    private final Map<String, Type<?>> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void addItem(String key, T t) {
        itemMap.put(key, new Type<>(t));
    }

    public Collection<Type<?>> getAllItems() {
        return itemMap.values();
    }

    public static class Type<T> {
        private final T value;
        public Type(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Type(" + value + ")";
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Container c = new Container();
        c.addItem("double", 1.0);
        c.addItem("string", "abc");
        System.out.println(c.getAllItems());
    }
}
```

The example is of course simplified, let's just assume there is a genuine reason for `Type<T>` to be generic.

A method that returns collection of all items (`getAllItems()`) is required by design. Items stored in `itemMap` can have different type - therefore the type parameter T cannot be moved up to Container class declaration.  For the same reason we cannot return `Collection<Type<T>>` as that would imply all items have the same type T which they don't. According to Effective Java there is either something wrong with this method or with this class API, neither of which seem to be true in my opinion.

I know that similar questions have been asked here before (e.g. [Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815023/generic-wildcard-types-should-not-be-used-in-return-parameters)) but they either focus on specific example, which is slightly different from mine, or have answers revolving around the fact that it doesn't make sense to return collections of form `Collection<? extends ...>` when instead a bounded type parameter can be used. That does not apply to the above use case (and I'm not interested in others because I can see how they can be addressed).

The question is this - if Effective Java is right (and so are other sources such as SonarQube rules and various articles on the web), what is the alternative to returning `Collection<Type<?>>` in the code above, or what is wrong with the design of class Container?

UPDATE:

A slightly modified/extended example to address some points raised in the comments (this is closer to the real code I'm working with):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Type<T> {
    private T value;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public Type(T value, Class<T> clazz) {
        this.value = value;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    Class<T> getItemClass() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

abstract class BaseContainer
{
    protected abstract Collection<Type<?>> getItems();
    // ... other methods
}

class Client {

    public void processItems(BaseContainer container) {
        Collection<Type<?>> items = container.getItems();
        for (Type<?> item: items) {
            processItem(item);
        }
    }

    public <T> void processItem(Type<T> item) {
        T currentValue = item.getValue();
        Class<T> clazz = item.getItemClass();
        T newValue = null;
        // ... calculate new value
        item.setValue(newValue);
    }
}
```

If `BaseContainer.getItems()` return type is declared as `Collection<Type<Object>>` we provide a loophole for "rogue" clients to put a value of invalid type into an instance of Type. It is for the same reason that `List<Object>` is not the same as `List<Integer>` - it is easy to see how returning former instead of latter would allow anybody to put as String into a List of integers (`List<Integer>` **is** however `List<? extends Object>`).

Following an approach suggested by @isi we could make Type implement some interface (non-generic) and use that in the return type of `getItems` instead. I can see how that can work. But in the real code that would mean a whole new interface mimicking most methods of the generic type without type parameter, which feels somewhat clumsy. It also looks like one essentially writes down the interface of `Type<T>` with T = Object, which is bordering on code duplication. In a way I see `Type<?>` as a convenient shorthand for avoiding this work and extra interface.

Comment: Can you please clarify how users of `Container` would use the return value of `getAllItems`?  The current example provides a `toString` override for `Type`.  Beyond that, in real-world usage, do the callers need to get back to the concrete type of each item?  If so, do you expect that to be done by runtime type checks and downcasting?  With the current example, I'm having trouble seeing why you wouldn't return `Collection<Type<Object>>`.

Comment: well the book is wrong, so is everybody who echoes the point :) Don't worry about it; if a method calls for a return type with wildcard, just do it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30548589/2158288

Comment: my article on wildcard - http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html

Answer (score 3):

If you truly intend to store objects of absolutely *any* type then use Object. There is no need to add type checking sugar when you specifically do not want types checked.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `Type` class silently provides two *interfaces*<sup>*</sup>. One for users which do care about the generic type `T`, and another one for users which don't. I'll try to make this a little clearer with some code:

```
interface TypeWithoutT { Object getValueObj(); } // exposes untyped api

class Type<T> implements TypeWithoutT { // exposes several apis
    private final T value;

    // exposes typed part of the api (can be on a separate interface)
    public T getValue() { return value; }
    public Type(T value) { this.value = value; }

    // overrides commonly available apis
    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Type(" + value + ")"; }

    // exposes untyped part of the api and Object's api
    public Object getValueObj() { return value; }
}
```

The *typed interface* of class `Type<T>` can expose more type specific operations as the opponent *untyped interface* `TypeWithoutT`. The `toString` method is available on every instance so it is part of the commonly available interface of `Object` instances. Probably, there will be other useful operations besides the ones provided by `Object`, which should be exposed to the user, which is the *untyped* part of the api.

## Rephrase

The question now is: What can a user do with a bunch of mixed `Type` instances? What do they expect of each instance within a mixed collection of `Type` instances?

## Is `Object` sufficent?

They probably expect nothing else, than the same set of operations which are common to all `Type<T>` instances for any of the possible choices of `T`. Like the `toString` method from `Object`. If that is all the API users need to know about using collections of `Type` instances, it should definitely suffice to use `Collection<Type<Object>>` as the return type on the `getAllItems` method.

## Or not?

If the API users expect much more than the interface provided by `Object` the above approach can be used to return a more specialized collection. In this case the return type of the `getAllItems` method could be changed to `Collection<TypeWithoutT>`.

This way it is possible to explicitly expose a useful API to both users - the one who cares about the type and the one who doesn't.

## However

I would stick with the best practices and not return a wildcard-ed type, except i have a really good reason for it. One of the given solutions should do - i guess.

---

*interface*<sup>*</sup>: I mean interface in the general sense and not explicitly java interfaces. Thus, something with a contract and a set of operations.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the answer I was looking for. It helps to think about this problem in terms of interfaces and probably provides solutions for most of similar kind of problems.

Comment: Pressed Enter too early...

I still don't entirely agree that one can return `Collection<Type<Object>>` in this example. `Type<Object>` is an instruction to compiler that `Type` contains `Object` (and not a subtype of `Object`). For instance, if  we had `Type<Integer>` and defined method `setValue(T)`, one could write `Object o = new Object(); type.setValue(o);` circumventing requirement that `Type` must contain an `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

> However in certain cases it appears to be the most optimal choice,
>   such as in code below:

But that's NOT a "wildcard type". A "wildcard type" would be something like `Foo<?>` or `Foo<? extends Something>` or `Foo<? super Something>`, where the type argument is a (possibly bounded) `?`. You can assign `Foo` of different type arguments to a variable of `Foo<?>` wildcard type. There's a kind of polymorphism that the wildcard type provides.

You are talking about the type `Collection<Type<?>>`. In this case, the type argument is `Type<?>`, which is a specific type. This is very different. There is a `?` in there somewhere, but it is at a deeper level. With something like `Collection<Type<?>>`, you can't assign `Collection` of different type arguments to a variable of type `Collection<Type<?>>`. The type argument is fixed to be `Type<?>`; nothing else is compatible.