# How to flatMap vavr Either with left variance annotated

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, vavr

My code

```
open class Fail(override val message: String, override val cause: Throwable?) : RuntimeException(message, cause)

data class ValidationFail(override val message: String, override val cause: Throwable?) : Fail(message, cause)
```

more fails will be defined there in the future

i have 2 functions

```
fun fun1(): Either<out Fail, A>
fun fun2(a: A): Either<out Fail, B>
```

when i try to invoke them like this `fun1().flatMap{fun2(it)}`
i got

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is (A!) -> Either<out Fail, B> but ((A!) -> Nothing)! was expected. Projected type Either<out Fail, A> restricts use of public final fun <U : Any!> flatMap(p0: ((R!) -> Either<L!, out U!>!)!): Either<L!, U!>! defined in io.vavr.control.Either
```

Code from vavr Either:

```
default <U> Either<L, U> flatMap(Function<? super R, ? extends Either<L, ? extends U>> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper, "mapper is null");
    if (isRight()) {
        return (Either<L, U>) mapper.apply(get());
    } else {
        return (Either<L, U>) this;
    }
}
```

I guess o have this error because there is `L` in flatMap definition not `? extends L`

Any workaround for this ?

Comment: I'm guessing your `Either` class is declared as `Either<L,R>` (the `R` seems to appear from nowhere). In your fail branch, you cast an `Either<L,R>` to `Either<L,U>`, which I think forces an inference that `R/U` must be `Nothing`.

Comment: Where does `B` in `fun fun2(a: A): Either<out Fail, B>` come from? And same for `A` in `fun1`.

Comment: Either is taken from vavr library. Both A and B are data types defined by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you can make it compile by removing `out` variance from `fun1` and `fun2` return type. [You shouldn't use wildcard types as return types anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22815270/10536125).

But it won't help if you have `fun1` and `fun2` defined this way:

```
fun fun1(): Either<ConcreteFail1, A>
fun fun2(a: A): Either<ConcreteFail2, B>
```

Replacing `L` with `? extends L` in `flatMap` signature will not help either because of `ConcreteFail2` not being a subtype of `ConcreteFail1`. The problem is that `Either` is supposed to be covariant, but there is no such thing as *declaration-site variance* in Java. Although there is a workaround using [`Either#narrow`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Either.html#narrow-io.vavr.control.Either-) method:

```
Either.narrow<Fail, A>(fun1()).flatMap { Either.narrow(fun2(it)) }
```

Of course, it looks odd and must be extracted to a separate extension function:

```
inline fun <L, R, R2> Either<out L, out R>.narrowedFlatMap(
    crossinline mapper: (R) -> Either<out L, out R2>
): Either<L, R2> = narrow.flatMap { mapper(it).narrow }
```

Where `narrow` is:

```
val <L, R> Either<out L, out R>.narrow: Either<L, R> get() = Either.narrow(this)
```

---

I think *Vavr* doesn't provide its own `narrowedFlatMap` because this method requires using a wildcard receiver type, so it can't be a member method and must be a static one, which breaks all readability of operations pipelining:

```
narrowedFlatMap(narrowedFlatMap(narrowedFlatMap(fun1()) { fun2(it) }) { fun3(it) }) { fun4(it) }
```

But since we use Kotlin, we can pipeline static (extension) functions as well:

```
fun1().narrowedFlatMap { fun2(it) }.narrowedFlatMap { fun3(it) }.narrowedFlatMap { fun4(it) }
```