# How to refactor method to avoid wild card return type?

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube

The below `get` method given Sonar issue:

> Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types.

I need some expert help to refactor this code to avoid that Sonar issue. I try different ways like `Entity<D.Id>` but I haven't idea how to combine with `Entity<C.Id>`.

```
public interface Identity {
  //
}

public interface Entity<I extends Identity> {
  //
}

public interface D
  extends Entity<D.Id>
{
}

public interface C
  extends Entity<C.Id>
{
}


protected Entity<? extends Identity> get(final String value)
 {
    if (value == 'valuD')
    {
      return new D() //return object;
    }
    else
    {
      return new C() //return object;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815023/generic-wildcard-types-should-not-be-used-in-return-parameters)

Comment: The issue looks like the same, but in this scenario, return an object. There are not saying, is there any way to fix it. (As example: Entity<D.Id> when put, it resolve but, I have to send Entity<C.Id> type also return .? so are there any way to combine both?)

Comment: The answer to that question says: `Better to use bounded type parameter. With bounded type parameter, the type will be inferred based on the type you pass, or the target type of the method invocation.`. In your case, that would probably be something like `<T extends Identity> Entity<T> get(final type type)`. Then the caller can write either `Entity<D.Id> d = get(D)` or `Entity<C.Id> c = get(C)`. Of course, nothing prevents `Entity<D.Id> x = get(C)`. You'd need to change `type`.

Comment: Is the type of `type` meant to be `int`?

Comment: no , type can be some condition .. it looks like , condition equal =1 , return C type object/