# Properly return list of class or of subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube

My situation is rather simple, I have a class `Parent` and a class `Child` which is extending `Parent`.

If I have a method getStuff that can return either an instance of Parent or of Child, I can simply do that:

```
public Parent getStuff(boolean p) {
  return p ? new Parent() : new Child();
}
```

Now what if my method can return either `List<Parent>` or `List<Child>`? I have to do that:

```
public List<? extends Parent> getListOfStuff(boolean p) {
  return p
    ? myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfParents()
    : myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfChilds();
}

public List<Parent> myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfParents() {
  return new ArrayList<Parent>();
}

public List<Child> myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfChilds(boolean p) {
  return new ArrayList<Child>();
}
```

But when I do that, Sonar reports ["Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types"](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452/) as a critical problem.

What is the proper way of fixing it?

Thanks

EDIT: the cleanest solution I've seen is ChristianRein's solution below (rebuild the `List<Child>` as a `List<Parent>`, it does exactly what I want and is so obvious in insight):

```
public List<Parent> getListOfStuff(boolean p) {
  return p
    ? myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfParents()
    : new ArrayList<Parent>(myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfChilds());
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact error in the question

Comment: Using `List<? extends Parent>` states that you get a list of `Parent` or a list of some subclass of `Parent`, that means, regarding type safety: (i) you cannot add any element to the list (example: `Parent` should not be added to `List<Child>`, `Child` not to `List<OtherChild`;) (ii) you can only expect `Parent` elements from such a list -- returning `List<Parent` *solves* both

Comment: @TimMoore sonar just says that "Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types".
@user16320675 the compiler doesn't allow simply returning `List<Parent>`, that's the point.

Comment: The reason I asked you to put the error message into the question (not just in a comment) is so that people can search for that error message and find this question in the future. Remember that the purpose of StackOverflow is to [to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). In fact, if you search for the error message, you might find existing helpful explanations, on both this site and others.

Comment: @user16320675 the problem is that I create both a List<Parent> and a List<Child>. Are you suggesting that I should convert the List<Child> to a List<Parent> ?

Comment: What does the caller do with the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815023/generic-wildcard-types-should-not-be-used-in-return-parameters)

Comment: `public List<Parent> getListOfStuff(boolean p) {}` should work

Comment: @TimMoore nothing really, it just returns it to the controller, which returns it to the client which made the http call. But it means the controller method also has wildard type as return parameter, and sonar isn't happy.

Comment: @Joe no, it just says it's bad to use wildcard types as return parameter, but not how one should do to avoid it.

Comment: @OlegCherednik no, I tried, the compiler doesn't accept it, which is why I had to use the wildcard.

Comment: I’m assuming that your actual code doesn’t return empty lists then, correct?

Comment: @TimMoore Indeed they aren't empty. Both methods return the list of the same elements, except that the second one performs a join on a second table to populate the additional attributes of the `Child` class. Depending on if I need that additional information, I call one method or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your class Child extends your class Parent, you can easily write

```
public class Parent {

    public List<Parent> getListOfStuff(final boolean p) {
        return p
                ? myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfParents()
                : new ArrayList<>(myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfChildren());
    }

    private List<Child> myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfChildren() {
        return List.of(new Child());
    }

    private List<Parent> myOtherMethodThatReturnsListOfParents() {
        return List.of(new Parent());
    }

}
```

This way, Sonar accepts it.

In the calling method, you may use instanceof to decide if you recieved a Child or a Parent object. In JUnit5, you may use assertInstanceOf:

```
@Test
void parents() {
    // when
    final List<Parent> result = new Parent().getListOfStuff(true);

    // then
    assertInstanceOf(Parent.class, result.get(0));
    assertInstanceOf(Child.class, result.get(0)); // fails
}

@Test
void children() {
    // when
    final List<Parent> result = new Parent().getListOfStuff(false);

    // then
    assertInstanceOf(Child.class, result.get(0));
    assertInstanceOf(Parent.class, result.get(0));
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference with my code. There is still a wildcard as a return parameter, sonar will still complain.

Comment: You were correct - shame on me. I corrected it - using parent accept all children, too.

Comment: That still doesn't work. This is what I tried first, the compiler doesn't accept it, because `List<Child>` isn't a subclass of `List<Parent>`.

Comment: Please have another look - I edited it again and added a test case.

Comment: I see, rebuild the `List<Child>` as a `List<Parent>`. That's a clean solution, thanks.