# Cast element in Java For Each statement

Tags: java, foreach, casting

Is it possible (or even advisable) to cast the element retrieved from a for each statement in the statement itself? I do know that each element in list will be of type `<SubType>`.

I.E.:

```
List<BaseType> list = DAO.getList();  
for(<SubType> element : list){ 
    // Cannot convert from element type <BaseType> to <SubType>
    ...
}
```

rather than:

```
List <BaseType> list = DAO.getList();
for(<BaseType> el : list){
    <SubType> element = (<SubType>)el;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you *really* know that each entry is going to be a subtype ? The DAO simply has to fulfill the `List<BaseType>` contract, and if you're assuming a subclass, then I think something is wrong somewhere. I'd perhaps concentrate more on getting the interface to the DAO correct, and have it contractually return what you want.

Comment: +1 for so eloquently stating the contract mechanism that interfaces should adhere to.

Comment: Unfortunately the DAO code isn't ours. However, the feeds into the datasource are. We subclassed <BaseType> (the only such subclass) since we wanted additional  functionality in the class.  Since we control the input and we're only putting <SubType> objects in there I feel I can be fairly certain that the retrieved object will actually be one of <SubType>.  If we controlled all the code, you would be 100% correct.

Comment: @Carl - is it worth wrapping the DAO then, and providing a *different* interface that does what you want. Otherwise you'll have to convert all across your code base (potentially - I realise I'm making assumptions about how widely distributed this is)

Comment: Ahh, but to be able to always see the forest for the trees.  That makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll pass it along to those who make such decisions.

Comment: @Brian you should add wrapping this last comment to the answer.

Comment: While this "reply" would be a really helpful comment, it doesn't reply the question at all. While the example says "My DAO is done poorly", the question asks for a solution to for-each element casting. This answer doesn't cover it at all. For example, I'd love to typecast javax.management.AttributeList entries to actual Attribute, as it extends ArrayList<Object> for some weird reason.

Answer (score 17):

For all the reasons stated by others, you shouldn't do this.  However, if you cannot change the interface, the following is possible:

```
for (BaseType element : list) {
    SubType subType = (SubType)element;
    ...
}
```

As far as I know, this is the only way to do this and remain truly type safe - i.e. not rely on type erasure to catch any problems, which it will not necessarily do until much later.

I realize this is not EXACTLY what you were looking for, but it does handle the casting.

Comment: I should note, that if you CAN change the interface, and it will ALWAYS be the SubType, you SHOULD change the interface, whether that is through a subclass extension or just changing it.

Comment: To be really safe, you could do: if(element instanceof SubType)

Comment: Very true - I should have put that.

Comment: Very good, this is what I have been doing.  I was hoping there was a shorter way, but I do see the wisdom in not having one.

Comment: A pity it cannot be done right in the for-each, but I guess this is not something you need frequently (unless you work with some really nasty code).

Answer (score 13):

It is in fact possible to combine the cast with the for loop, like so:

```
List<BaseType> list = DAO.getList();  
for (SubType subType : ((List<SubType>) list)){ 
    ...
}
```

Or you can use this slightly-cleaner pattern:

```
List<SubType> list = (List<SubType>) DAO.getList();  
for (SubType subType : list){ 
    ...
}
```

You will get an unchecked cast warning from the Java compiler, unless you suppress it.  The effect of the first form will be effectively identical to casting each element within the loop.  The second form will also enforce that new additions to the list must conform to SubType.

Note that this will NOT work with arrays, since arrays have distinct runtime types.  In other words, BaseType[] is not castable to SubType[].  You can use the Arrays API to work around this, like so:

```
BaseType[] array = DAO.getArray();
for (SubType subType : Arrays.<SubType>asList(array)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Those casts are not legal, although you can do [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java) to work around it (like an intermediate cast to `List<?>`.)  The [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) linked from that question notes: "Although Integer is a subtype of Number, List<Integer> is not a subtype of List<Number> and, in fact, these two types are not related. The common parent of List<Number> and List<Integer> is List<?>."

Comment: The second example will work if DAO.getList returns an untyped List rather than List<BaseType>. The pattern can be useful when dealing with a legacy codebase where none of the collections are typed.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes! but god forbid, Why? My early attempts in my career did that and I have learnt. Programming to interfaces always has an advantage. I always get questions from junior developers about handling cases where only subtypes have the methods/functionality required.

Say Animal class with Dog subtype having method bark(). They want bark() functionality. The actual challenge is that they want a behaviour of animal communication not bark() but animal speak(). So a new Cat sub class would not require meow(). What about this then:- My dog's form a pack, but cats don't. The answer pack() behaviour is not owned by a single dog. Pack is a different aspect, pass a pack to all objects and ask the objects to join the pack. (Visitor pattern/Adapter pattern). My Wolf class can use the same behaviour.

Am I rigid about this, no if it is only 1 off instance I am fine. If the answer is I am not sure, then you better play safe by working at interface contracts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not partial to Google collections, you can wrap the list with `transform` method. In your case it will be very efficient and totally compliant.  I would put it as a wrapper method though as Brian has suggested.

```
public List< SubType > fromDao ( )
{
    // Put a comment for maintainer

    // Lists from DAO always contain SubTypes
    return
        Lists.transform(
            DAO.getList( ),
            new Function< BaseType, SubType >( )
            {
                public SubType apply ( final BaseType from )
                {
                    return (SybType) from;
                }
            };
}
```