# How to cast to child class in a for loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap, subclass

I've got this for-each-loop, with boxenModel as a subclass of technikModel.
I iterate over a keySet from a HashMap of technikModels.

```
for(boxenModel t : getBox().keySet()) {
            
}
```

Can I cast the technikModel from the keySet to a boxenModel in the for-each loop or will I have to do that in the body of the loop?

Comment: You want to cast to a **child** class, not parent unlike you wrote in the title.

Comment: Duplicate of this I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480316/cast-element-in-java-for-each-statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast element in Java For Each statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480316/cast-element-in-java-for-each-statement)