# How to cast from List<Object> to List<A> or List<? extends A>?

Tags: java, list, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you cast a List of objects from one type to another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java)

Searched the internet a little, and found no nice way of doing it... My solution now is:

```
public class A {}
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
obj.add(new A());
// Ugly solution here:
List<A> a = (List<A>) (List) obj;
```

But this is quite ugly and gets a warning. No "official" way of doing this?

EDIT: To the guys who closed this: I was aware of the solution posted in [How do you cast a List of objects from one type to another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java) It is the same as the one I posted in my question (just adding the `<?>`  after the first cast does exactly the same) I Was looking for something more "clean". In the direction of using the `Class<?> clazz = listobj.get(0).getClass` way of getting the class and casting to the correct class at runtime (but no idea if something like that works... Eclipse doesn't seem to like it anyway...)

Comment: Why are you creating a `List<Object>` in the first place?

Comment: @AdamArold Thank you for your answer. Yes I should have been more specific: The `List<Object>` come from the fact that I'm fetching in a database with JDBC and that I don't necessarily know the datatype that will come out. Obviously I'm not creating `List<Object>` for fun ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
obj.add(new A());
```

It is not the right way to write code. Basically you are creating a generic List and adding Object to it and it type unsafe and keep any Object type.

```
List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
obj.add(new A());
obj.add(new String("str"));
obj.add(1);
```

It is recommended to create type-safe `List` like `List<A> obj = new ArrayList<A>();`

you can do this in such a way -

```
public <T>List<T> castCollection(List srcList, Class<T> clas){
    List<T> list =new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object obj : srcList) {
    if(obj!=null && clas.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
        list.add(clas.cast(obj));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I should have been more specific: The `List<Object>` come from the fact that I'm fetching in a database with JDBC and that I don't necessarily know the datatype that will come out. Obviously I'm not creating `List<Object>` for fun ^^

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes this seems like a solution that will go in the direction that I like. I'll check it out. Since this is the best answer I got I'll validate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

So why isn't your list declared as

```
List<A> obj = new ArrayList<A>();
```

to begin with ?

It's really dangerous to do what you're trying to do. What you're saying is that your list contains `A`s and subclasses thereof. But since it's originally a list of `Object`s (i.e. anything). You're likely to get a nasty surprise later on.

What that compiler error really means is that somewhere you have a design issue.

Comment: +1 This is the nice way of doing it, even if it's not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @BrianAgnew Thank you for your answer. Yes maybe I'm having a design flaw then, but when I use apache's [commons-dbutils-1.5.jar](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) for JDBC, I designed it that way that it can fetch any data type from databases. Hence the `List<Object>`. But for later use, I need to cast them to their java type... Am I using JDBC completely wrong here then? (I have no experience with it, just started coding :))

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the issue is that you want to put objects of different (but inheritance-related) types into the list? In that case, you read the [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), especially the parts about `<? extends Something>` and `<? super Something>`

Cheers,