# java cast ArrayList<StringBuilder> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java

I'm writing a method in java which requires `ArrayList<String>` as its output. 
In this method, String concatenation is frequently used. I use `StringBuilder` instead of String since `String` is more expensive in concatenation.

Before returning result, how could I cast all elements in `ArrayList<StringBuilder>` to `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Do you mean: how can I cast all elements in `ArrayList<StringBuilder>` to `String`? You can't _cast_ them.

Comment: I reopened the question because [How do you cast a List of objects from one type to another in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447) concerns casting a list of supertypes to a list of subtypes, whereas `StringBuilder` and `String` are unrelated. @SotiriosDelimanolis you could add your `Stream#map` answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how could I cast all elements in `ArrayList<StringBuilder>` to `ArrayList<String>`?

You can't and you shouldn't. Make it an ArrayList of one or the other.

Or if you must translate, then you'll need a for loop to iterate through the collection, building the new collection.

or I suppose you could declare the variable as an `ArrayList<? extends CharSequence>`  -- nope that wouldn't work as we're nixed since we can't `add(...)` anything into a covariant structure, so we wouldn't be able to add anything to this list, just read from it.

Comment: Use the new `Stream#map(Function)` functionality!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I'm not familiar with that -- please make an answer with that information so we all can learn!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sotirios meant something like `List<String> listOfString = listOfStringBuffers.stream().map(builder->builder.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList())`. BTW lambda expression `builder->builder.toString()` can be also written as `StringBuilder::toString`.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks! I've been putting off learning Lambdas and Java 8 for too long.

Comment: I was afk. That is what I meant. Your answer is plenty. This is just an implementation of what you described.