# How to consume a List<Sub> being returned as List<Super>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that returns `List<Super>`.
say
    `List<Super> myMethod();`

When calling that method, I want to cast the returned list to `List<Sub>`, knowing that its runtime type will be a `List` of `Sub`.

I know that `List<Sub> subs = (List<Sub>) myMethod()` won't work because generics are invariant.

However, `List<? super Sub> subs = myMethod()` works, the compile time type becomes `List<Object>`, so `subs.get(0).mySubMethod()` won't work.

What I end up with is that I have to explicitly cast it as `((Sub) subs.get(0)).mySubMethod()`

How do I do this correctly without explicit casting on each element?

Comment: If you take generics & List our of the equation - can you call the 'mySubMethod' when you have 'Super' object without explicit casting anyway?

Comment: I think this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes  Short version is `List<Sub> subs = (List<Sub>)(List<?>)myMethod();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest version is:

```
List<Sub> subs = (List) myMethod();
```

`List` is a "raw type"; you can convert from `List` to any `List<...>` without a cast.

Note that this is circumventing the type system in a fundamentally incorrect way; the list was constructed as an `ArrayList<Super>` (or similar), so it's actually incorrect to trick the compiler into letting you refer to it with a reference of type `List<Sub>`, even if it so happens that all of the list elements are of type `Sub`. (The same is true of msandiford's longer version above; it may look more generics-friendly, but it's actually just another way of doing the same fundamentally incorrect thing.)

But, due to type erasure, you can generally get away with it.

---

One *correct* approach would be to make the method itself generic:

```
<T extends Super> List<T> myMethod(final Class<T> clazz) {
    final List<T> ret = Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList<T>(), clazz);
    // ... add elements to ret ...
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a pearl.