# Cannot cast List<Object> return type of HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to get records using HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria).

It is returning List and I am trying to cast it to List but it does not allow me for that. How to cast List to List?

Here is my code example:

```
public List<User> getUserList(String status, String type)
    {
        DetachedCriteria joinCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserDetails.class)
                                                        .add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
        DetachedCriteria criteria = joinCriteria.createCriteria("user")
                                                .add(Restrictions.eq("type", type));


        return (List<User>) template.findByCriteria(criteria); // Gives error "Cannot cast from List<Object> to List<User>"
    }
```

Comment: i think you dont need to cast

Comment: Try this cast http://stackoverflow.com/a/933600/4807777

Comment: @Chintan Patel post complete exception stack trace, seems to be issue with your criteria you have built.

Comment: from where is the variable `template` come from?

Comment: @LaurentiuL.your trick worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @kucing_terbang it is object of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you have already noticed, Java does not extend the subclass relation to templates. This means that if you have two classes `A` and `B`, where `B extends A`, then `C<B>` is not a subclass of `C<A>`, which is exactly what the compiler is trying to tell you. The [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) also tells you about that. Even though "hack" linked to by @laurentiu-l works, you might want to consider this alternative solution which is a little bit less "hacky" in my opinion:

```
final List<User> returnValue = new LinkedList<>();
for(Object user : template.findByCriteria(criteria)) {
  returnValue.add((User)user);
}
return returnValue;
```

---

A little bit of background as to why Java does not extend subclassing to generics. Asssume it did and consider the following three classes:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }
```

Now we write the following code:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new LinkedList<>();

// Perfectly fine, since Dog extends Animal
List<Animal> animalList = dogList;

// Fine again, since a Cat is an Animal, so we can put it in the list
animalList.add(new Cat());

// Oops...
Dog dog = dogList.get(0);
```

This code would compile perfectly, but throw an error at runtime. In order to avoid such complications, Java just outlawed this extension of subtyping to generics completely.

Comment: Nice explaination Alexander. I was aware of this fact but just skipped for the moment. But you have explained it very well. Now it will never skip from my mind. Thanks :)