# Convert List<Object> to List<CustomClass>

Tags: java

I am returning a `List` of objects with just the type `Object`. However I know that these objects are of class `CustomClass` in this case.

When I attempt to cast the original list to the `CustomClass` I get an error.

This is how I'm working around it currently and it works but I don't like the fact I have a `for loop` just to do this.

```
List<Object> objects = getObjects();
List<CustomClass> customObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Object object : objects ) {
            if ( object instanceof CustomClass )
                customObjects.add( (CustomClass) object );
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your `getObjects()` method to return `List<CustomClass>`?

Comment: Code for getObjects please? What's the error? ClassCastException?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate (though did not search for "it"). However, this is the usual way to do it (although it could be generalized, e.g. to have a utility method like `List<Custom> c = filter(objects, Custom.class);`)

Comment: Not really it's a database method where I pass in an object factory that creates the objects I want...

Comment: @SMA: There is no error. The OP just wants to eliminate the ugly for-loop.

Comment: There it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes . However, you should **NOT** use the "accepted answer" from there (how the heck could this get so many upvotes?)

Comment: @Marco13.  This hack was explicitly allowed for backward compatibilty with existing non-generic libraries.  Looks like OP here has a valid case for using this hack.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak This is worse than a non-generic library, it's a badly genericized library.

Comment: @biziclop.  Unfortunately, there are plenty of those out there too.  And usually these are the ones that management picks up/pays license fees for.  Sigh...

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak & @biziclop, what's the alternative here? It's a method to get a list of rows from a database and I pass in a factory of a certain type which is use to create objects of my `CustomClass`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know in advance that all of your objects are actually `CustomClass` objects, you can perform an unsafe cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<CustomClass> list = (List<CustomClass>)(List<?>)getObjects();
```

This is the fastest solution; practically in runtime nothing is performed except the variable assignment. However if you're wrong and your list actually contains other objects, you may have an unexpected `ClassCastException` later.

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself doing this kind of filtering/casting often, you can write your own type-safe generic method:

```
List<Object> objects = getObjects();
List<CustomClass> customObjects = myFilter(objects, CustomClass.class);

static <E> List<E> myFilter(List<?> lst, Class<E> cls) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    for (Object obj : lst) {
        if (cls.isInstance(obj))
            result.add(cls.cast(obj));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely, positively sure that your list contains only `CustomClass` objects, you can do this, and silence a lot of warnings in the process

```
// Note, absense of generic parameter here, this is a first warning you will see
List genericList = getObjects( );

// Expect another 'unchecked' warning here
List< CustomClass > typedList = (List<CustomClass>) genericList;
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tips: 
When preparing the `List`, ensure you add `CustomClass` objects to the list.

```
customObjects.add( (CustomClass) object );
```

When returning object from your method `getObjects()`, this will return list of `CustomClass` and not list of `Object`.

```
List<CustomClass> objects = getObjects();
```

Hope this helps.