# Casting from ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<Custom> class throws error while Object to Custom does not

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList deserializedArray that I have received by de-serializing JSON using GSON. I have my own class called Post. When I try to do this

```
 ArrayList<Post> posts =  (ArrayList<Post>) deserializedArray;
```

It throws exception saying in convertible types. But when I do this

```
Post P = (Post) deserializedArray.get(0);
```

This works fine.I am trying to understand why the first one doesn't work even though the second case works ?

Edit : I have been pointed to the solution. But what I really want to know is the inner workings of Java and why are there special restriction for lists ?

Comment: Please post the exact stack trace and deserialization logic.

Comment: Also post the json you are deserialising (smallest amount that reproduces the error) and the Post class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Comment: certainly very similar - I have linked to it in my answer and will let the asker decide whether they really needed to cast, or if they just don't know how to use generics with GSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted way to do what you are trying to do is to use the Gson concept of a [TypeToken](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples). By using a TypeToken you elminate the need to cast at all (Gson will do this for you).

As for understanding why you get your particular error, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes).

Comment: I know about type token. My question is geared towards "why" . I already know the solution . I just couldn't figure out why this should happen

Comment: I see. In that case the question is a duplicate as pointed out by Mrinal.

Comment: Well, it's only a duplicate if the suggested solution also works in this case! let us know