# Java how to cast a whole List

Tags: java

How to cast a complete list without iterating through it in Java.
I have this function:

```
private List<Object> getItems (List<Object> list, Pagination pagination) {

        if (list.size() > pagination.getItemsXPage()) {

            int init = (pagination.getCurrentPage()-1)* pagination.getItemsXPage();
            int end =  init +  pagination.getItemsXPage();

            if (end > list.size()) {
                end = list.size();
            }

            return list.subList(init, end);

        } else {

            return list;                        
        }       

    }
```

I want to do this but it is not possible ?

```
List<ApplicationSearchItem> applicationSearchItem = (List) getItems (list, searchCriteria.getCategoryProductsPagination());
```

Comment: Short answer: you cannot. Long answer: create a new `List<ApplicationSearchItem>` and copy each element, one by one, by casting it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you would use generic methods declaration :

> By now, you will have learned to avoid the beginner's mistake of trying to use Collection< Object > as the type of the collection parameter. You may or may not have recognized that using Collection< ? > isn't going to work either. Recall that you cannot just shove objects into a collection of unknown type.

[from oracle generic methods tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

The return type is defined by the type of the parameter list :

```
private <T> List<T> getItems (List<T> list, Pagination pagination) {
 ... 
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but since the method doesn't use any fields, it should be `static` too.

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you either have to cast each object individually, or change the parameter of your method from `List<Object>` to List`<ApplicationSearchItem>`to avoid using a cast.

The reason you can't simply cast an entire list is because a list is merely a reference holder; the actual list only points to the object types and ensures that only objects of the right type are in the list. In the memory itself, the objects still exist independent of the list, so either way, they're going to be individually cast to convert their types.

By doing what dok says (other answer), your method can accept objects of any type and operate on them. Alternatively, you can have it only accept lists where you don't need to make casts.