# Type casting in Java parametrized lists

Tags: java, list, casting, type-conversion

**Setup**

I have two classes:

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}
```

And a List of type `B`:

```
List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Part 1: Objective**

What I'm effectively trying to achieve is to convert the type of `listOfB` from `B` to `A`. Following the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html), I'm assuming the correct way to do this is something along the lines of:

```
List<? extends A> listOfB = new ArrayList<>();
listOfB.add(new B()); // <--- Error here
List<A> listOfA = (List<A>) listOfB;
```

However this does not allow me to add objects of class `A` or `B`  to `listOfB`. The error I get is:

> add `(capture <? extends A>)` in List cannot be applied to `(B)`

Thus I'm currently resorting to the following method (which works perfectly fine):

```
List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<A>(listOfB);
```

**Part 2: Efficiency**

Apparently there are not-so-good-ways of doing this ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/933600/2153244)) and the recommended way in the Java tutorials ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)).

So whats the correct way to achieve this with `List<? extends A>`?

And I'd like to know the performance loss/gain of above methods. Does the constructor iterate thought `listOfB` to do type conversion? If so, does this effect the performance as the list becomes larger (compared to direct type conversion in Part 1)?

Comment: You might want to read up on [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super); it may help explain what's going on and why. As for your part 2, the constructor will iterate through `listOfB` to insert elements into the new ArrayList, but there's no conversion involved (nor would it be needed, since the references are _already_ of type A). The constructor just copies the references.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `List <? extends A>` the meaning is that some unknown type elements which extend A resides on the list and only elements of that type. You cannot make any assumptions about the concrete type of the elements, thus you cannot add a B to your list. You wont be able to add anything since the compiler does not know the concrete  type.

When you define your `List <B>`, since Lists are covariants in java, it means that even if B extends A, `List <B>` doesnt extend `List <A>`! That makes sense: if you could do that, than look at this example: 
String extends Object right?
Then you could do:

```
List <String> a = new List <>();
a.add ("bla");
List <Object> asObj = a;
asObj.add (1);
```

And than if you try to  iterate over a you think you get a list of strings but youll get a ClassCastException!

So, the question is why not defining your list as List of As?

Casting doesnt involve constructor iteration. The compiler just replaces the type erasures with the concrete types before runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the way to go, `ArrayList` can just do an array copy of the internal data.

The reason why adding a `B` to `List<? extends A>` doesn't work, is that `?` could be a subtype of `B` or a sibling. So it is unsafe to add a `B` to it.

i.e.

```
class C extends A {}
...
List<? extends A> listOfC = new ArrayList<C>(); // perfectly valid
listOfC.add(new B()); // uh oh, adding B to list of C!...
```