# casting down generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I need to know how to cast down generics in Java. i.e solving for this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Map<String,Object>> to List<Map>
```

I have a method in an external class returning `List<Map<String,Object>>` to me but i have to pass that down to another method in another class that only takes `List<Map>`. I cannot change either of those 2 external classes, so changing signatures is out of the question, I also cannot so what can i do to to be able to cast it down? I'm using Java 6, so the "diamond" operator introduced in Java 7 will not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for those of you facing the same problem, the solution is to do a cast but it has to be as follows:

```
(List<Map>)(List<?>)
```