# Handling List<Interface> without type casting in java

Tags: java

Imagine this scenario.

```
MyInterface{
    method1();
    method2();
    ...
}

MyImpl1 implements MyInterface{
    ...
}

MyImpl2 implements MyInterface{
    ...
}

SomeOtherClass{
    ...
    public List<MyInterface> foo();
}


Service1{
    public List<Impl1> service1Impl(){
        SomeOtherClass obj = new SomeOtherClass(...); 
        return (List<Impl1>)obj.foo()
    }
}

Service2{
    public List<Impl2> service2Impl(){
        SomeOtherClass obj = new SomeOtherClass(...);
        return (List<Impl2>)obj.foo()
    }
}
```

SomeOtherClass.java's foo() could return either `List<MyImpl1>` or `List<MyImp2>` based on the arguments passed in its constructor. In Service1 lets say it returns `List<Impl1>`, In the case of Service2 class the obj.foo() would return `List<Impl2>`.

Is there a way for me to avoid that explicit type casting? I am thinking of making the Service1's foo() method return List instead of List without type casting it before I return.

Comment: Couldn't you change the return type to `List<MyInterface>` for both service methods?

Comment: Looks to me like `SomeOtherClass` should be generic - `SomeOtherClass<T extends MyInterface>` with the `foo` method returning `List<T>`

Comment: Most of the time, this indicates that you have a design problem. Why do you *need* to know the specific return types? The point of an interface is that `foo()` and `bar()` should each do the semantically equivalent thing, possibly with different implementations behind the scenes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a `List<MyInterface>` might not contain all instances of the appropriate subclass, `Impl1` or `Impl2`.

The only (clean) way to do this is to make `SomeOtherClass` generic:

```
class SomeOtherClass<T extends MyInterface>{
  public List<T> foo();
}
```

Then:

```
class Service1 {
    public List<Impl1> service1Impl(){
        SomeOtherClass<Impl1> obj = new SomeOtherClass<>(...);
        return obj.foo();
    }
}

class Service2 {
    public List<Impl2> service2Impl(){
        SomeOtherClass<Impl2> obj = new SomeOtherClass<>(...);
        return obj.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is lot cleaner agreed, but I still would have the warning `Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List<T>'.` right

Comment: @Wizard really? Where?

Comment: In the Service class's serviceImpl method's return statement. When I implement this I get the warning I mentioned above. `Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List<Impl1>'` to be precise in this case.

Comment: @Wizard then you've not implemented things correctly. I'd guess you've declared `public List foo()` in `SomeOtherClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: All we know, given the method signature, is that `SomeOtherClass` returns a list of `MyInterface` objects.  We know nothing more about what these objects are, whether they are a list of `Impl1`s, a list of `Impl2`s, or a list of some other implementation.

Let's say, for the sake of illustration, that `SomeOtherClass` returns a list of `JoesNewImplementation`.  You cast this in your `service1Impl` to a list of `Impl1`, and then you try to get an item out of the list.  The `ClassCastException` will naturally follow.

Ideally, this is the kind of thing that can be caught at compile time.  Your casting effectively overrides this safety check that the compiler is offering.