# Cast from List<T> in Map entry value to Set<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have a `Map<String,Object>` with an entry that contains a value of `List<String>`. I need to get the contents of the `List<String>` into a `Set<String>`. I am using the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = SomeObj.getMap();
if (map.get("someKey") instance of List<?>) {

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>((List<String>) map.get("someKey"));
}
```

My Eclipse-based IDE has a couple of warnings on this line:

- Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to 
  List

The code compiled and runs as it is intended to. Is there a better way to do this though? Annotating the line with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is my last and least preferred option.

Comment: Why is the value type of the map `Object`?

Comment: That is dictated by the library I am using. `getMap()` return type is `Map<String,Object>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Map<String, Object> map = SomeObj.getMap();
String key = "someKey";
if (map.get(key) instanceof List<?>) {
    List<?> list = (List<?>) map.get(key);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    // Cast and add each element individually
    for (Object o : list) {
        set.add((String) o);
    }
    // Or, using streams
    Set<String> set2 = list.stream().map(o -> (String) o).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Note: this isn't much safer but doesn't get a warning. +1

Comment: It is a bit safer though, because you find out in this code if an element isn't an object, as opposed to finding out much much later when you try to take the element out!

Comment: (note that an alternative way to write the map cast is `.map(String.class::cast)`).

Comment: Okay, I wouldn't have even thought of `String.class::cast`, even though `cast` has been there since Java 1.5!! Is there any advantage to using this as opposed to `.toString()`?

Comment: `null.toString()` throws a NPE, but `(String) null` and `String.class.cast(null)` don't.

Answer (score 3):

`String` is peculiar, in that a method exists on all objects to convert to it, namely `Object.toString()`. Invoking `toString()` on a String returns itself.

So, if you know it's a `List<?>`, you can convert to a `Set<String>` as follows:

```
List<?> list = (List<?>) map.get("some key");
Set<?> set = list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

(You may need to handle null elements)

Comment: In terms of `null` you might want to filter them, or use `.map(String::valueOf)` +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey only if you want `"null"` for null elements; if you want to keep them as `null`, you'd have to use something else.

Comment: I got identical answers and voted for the one that came in first. Thanks to both, I was able to get away from the error, as well as filter out null values in the list... I had not taken care of that case, because the [API](https://static.javadoc.io/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/4.0/com/nimbusds/jwt/JWTClaimsSet.html#getClaims()) will return a map out of key-value pairs that it parses out from the JWT token.

Comment: @WebUser the point about this answer is that it is unconditionally safe (once nulls are handled), because there are no casts other than the one to cast the object to a list; the other approach will fail at runtime if any of the list elements are not strings.

Comment: Which part of the other answer will fail, if any of the list elements are not strings? The method using streams or the first one? In both, it seems like the object is being cast to type String.

Comment: @WebUser the cast to a String will fail if it is not a String, in both the stream and non-stream approaches.

Answer (score -2):

You can't "cast" from List<> to Set<>; these are different interfaces with different methods.  But you can instead do...

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(map.get("someKey"));
```

This takes advantage of addAll's knowledge of the Collection interface.

Comment: The types don't match up, `map.get("someKey")` is an `Object`

Comment: Ah, I missed that he had a mix of object types in the Map.