# How to convert a generic Object to List<Entity> with no unchecked cast warning on JDK 11

Tags: java, lambda, java-11

Let's say I have an Object parameter on a method, I'd like to cast it on a List using lambda.

This is my code, I'm using JDK 11:

```
Optional.ofNullable(myobject).map(o -> (List<MyEntity>)o).ifPresent(o -> {
   // should be ok, however, I get an unchecked cast warning because of (List<String>)o
});
```

Actually I could also do the follow, but I loose reference to MyEntity:

```
Optional.ofNullable(myobject).map(List.class::cast).ifPresent(o -> {
   // Simply converted to a generic List
});
```

Any hints?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464674/14955

Comment: What is the declared type of `myobject`?

Comment: @Andreas it's simply Object

Comment: Why don’t you fix the parameter type?

Comment: because I can't. Take a look at JSR-352 specs on chunk processing

Comment: You can't avoid the warning, but you can suppress it. Your IDE should help you with that.

Comment: @FabrizioStellato As a starting point, what brings in the need of wrapping a `List<T>` into an `Optional`? Make changes prior to this, to avoid ending up with such wrapping.

Comment: that list might be null because is a persisted data serialized through batch process