# Java Generics: Cannot cast List<Class<R>> to List<Class>

Tags: java, generics

I have dto with parameter

```
public class FullResultDto<E extends Result> {
    private Integer priority;
    private E entity;
}
```

And i need retern List without it, but i 
can't cast "a".

```
public abstract class AlgorithmIncident<R extends Result> implements Algorithm {

     public List<FullResultDto<Result>> call(String user, String operationId) throws Exception {
          RulesEntity rule = refRulesRepo.findOneByRuleCode(getRuleId());
          List<FullResultDto<Result>> a = (List<FullResultDto<Result>>) 
          call(user, operationId, rule);//wont cast
          return a;
     }

     public List<IncidentFullResultDto<R>> call(String user, String operationId, RulesEntity rule) throws Exception {
          //some code
          //calculateIncidents - abstract method and defined in subClass 
          List<ResultDto<R>> result = calculateIncidents(); 
          return result;
    }
}
```

who faced this, and can explain?

Comment: There may be code missing. Why does the return value of the method call work with the value you return. You are returning `List<ResultDto>` but claiming to return `List<IncidentFullResultDto>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting generics in Java doesn't work, this is a limitation with the generics system. A work-around is to first cast `a` to a `List<?>`, and then a `List<List<FullResultDto<Result>>` like this:

```
List<FullResultDto<Result>> a = (List<FullResultDto<Result>>)(List<?>) call(user, operationId, rule);
```

This is a bit of a hacky solution and will result in a warning because the compiler cannot ensure that this is a safe cast. If possible, consider rewriting your code so there is no need for this unsafe cast.

---

Edit: A safer alternative is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464674/6426446):

> A more type-safe way of converting from a `List<Supertype>` to a `List<Subtype>` is to actually filter the list, and create a new list that contains only elements that have certain type.