# No instance of type variables exists so that Object confirms to Number

Tags: java

Why is the below code throwing this error : No instance of type variables exists so that Object confirms to Number?

```
List<Object> source = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Number> dest = Arrays.asList(4.1,5,6,9.1);
Collections.copy(dest, source);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [cast the source `List`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes) to make your code work:

```
Collections.copy(dest, (List<Number>) (List) source);
```

Please note that this code will throw an obscure exception (`ArrayStoreException`) if `source` contains non-number elements. Perhaps you should reconsider storing numbers in a list of `Object`.

You can't copy a list of `Object` to a list of `Number` because of the signature of  [`Collections.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)):

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

These two constraints basically guarantee that you can't directly copy a list of supertypes to a list of subtypes.

On JDK 8 you get a slightly more helpful error message:

```
Main.java:14: error: method copy in class Collections cannot be applied to given types;
Collections.copy(dest, source);
           ^
  required: List<? super T>,List<? extends T>
  found: List<Number>,List<Object>
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    lower bounds: Number,Object
    lower bounds: Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>copy(List<? super T>,List<? extends T>)
```

Comment: Thanks! How is the value of <T> determined when different data types are passed to different arguments?

Comment: @PunterVicky Basically, the compilator is trying to find a type that satisfies all the bounds in method and variable declarations. This process is called "type inference" and it can get quite complicated in some cases. There's a whole chapter in specification dedicated to this topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-18.html

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `Collections.copy`:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {}
```

you find out that both arguments should be `List` and `dest` should be higher in the hierarhy than `src`. In your example - `Number <- Object` so you have `ComplieTimeException`.

If you do like this:

```
Collections.copy(source, dest);
```

you're not going to have such error.

Answer (score 1):

It's because all elements in dest array must be of type `Number` but there's no guratantee that objects in source array are of this type cause they are of type `Object` and can be whatever.

please see:

```
    List<Object> source = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,"string allowed here");
    List<Number> dest = Arrays.asList(4.1,5,6,9.1);
    Collections.copy(dest, source);
```