# Is it possible to cast an instance of List<ArrayList<Integer>> to List<List<Integer>> in O(1) time in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have an instance of `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`, how can I change it to type `List<List<Integer>>` ?

My solution is:

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add(new ArrayList<>());
list1.add(new ArrayList<>());

List<List<Integer>> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

However, this method takes time `O(n)`, with `n` the length of `list1`.

**Question1:** Is there better method?

The following naive method is compile error:

```
List<List<Integer>> list2 = (List<List<Integer>>) list1;
```

**Question2**: why is above method compile error?

PS: It's from a practical problem. I just simplify the production code to above question. In production code, it's `List<SomeList>`, the `SomeList` implements `List` interface but has some special functions not declared in `List`. In intermediate process, we require the content must be `SomeList` since we have to use these special functions. However, in the end we just need to ouput our result to `List<List>` for other group to use.

Comment: Why aren't you just declaring it as `List<List<E>>` in the first place?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It's from a practical problme. I just simplify it to above question. In production code, it's `List<SomeList>`, the   `SomeList` implements `List` but have some special functions. In intermediate computation, we require the content must be `SomeList` since we need to use this special function. However, in the end we just need to ouput our result to `List<List>` for other group to use.

Comment: What about using `List<? extends List<Integer>>` as the type of `list2`? It is much safer, and I think in this context it is quite suitable.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. I've updated my question. Is `List<? extends List<Integer>>` suitable in my use case in the last part? I will also test it in my IDE. Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem with casting to `List<List<Integer>>` (like in enzo's answer) is that you can now add things that aren't `ArrayList`s to `list1` by doing e.g. `list2.add(new LinkedList<>());` And then if you do `ArrayList<Integer> foo = list1.get(2);`, an exception would occur, because the thing at index 2 is not an `ArrayList`. If you use `List<? extends List<Integer>>`, it doesn't allow you to add anything to `list2` except `null` so it's safer. Since this is for "output", I don't think whoever is using it needs to add anything to the list, so you should use `List<? extends List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an answer to your Question 2: The reason that your naive cast does not work is because it could lead to type errors. Consider for example the following code snippet:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> list2 = (List<List<String>>) list; // Wrong cast
list2.add(new LinkedList<>());
list.get(0).ensureCapacity(42); // Oops, LinkedList does not have this method.
```

As to your Question 1: A type-safe method to do exactly what you want in O(1) does not exist. You could fool the type system using raw types:

```
List<List<String>> list2 = (List) list;
```

But this would simply allow the kind of problems described above without the compiler error. But if you're sure the list will never change afterwards, it may be allowable. Sometimes. But probably you really shouldn't.

Better would be to change the type of your second list to `List<? extends List<String>>`. This would effectively prohibit adding elements to the list through the new reference, because the compiler cannot determine the type of List in `list2` from its type:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends List<String>> list2 = (List<? extends List<String>>) list;
list2.add(new LinkedList<>()); // Not possible anymore
list2.add(new ArrayList<>()); // Also not possible
```

Comment: Actually, there is a way: `List<List<String>> list2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);` Since the resulting list does not support adding elements, the described problem can not occur and relaxing the type signature is possible, Since this is just a wrapper around the original list, it is `O(1)`. Further, it’s worth noting that a `List<? extends List<String>>` does not prohibit adding elements in general. You can still add `null` and you may pass it to a method expecting an arbitrary `List<T>`, then, this method can retrieve elements from the list and add them again.

Answer (score -2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/933600/9997212):

```
List<List<Integer>> list2 = (List<List<Integer>>)(List<?>) list1;
```