# Problem combining Delay Queue and Executor Service

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, blockingqueue

I'm trying to create an Executor Service using a DelayQueue for the blocking queue with Java 8.
I created a class that implements Runnable and Delayed, and implemented the required methods:

```
public class CurlEvent implements Runnable, Delayed {...}
```

I constructed the queue, then the ExecutorService:

```
BlockingQueue<CurlEvent> queue = new DelayQueue<>();
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threads, threads, 36, TimeUnit.HOURS, queue);
```

The compiler flagged an error for the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor, even though CurlEvent implements Runnable:

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<com.dtna.web.test.playback.CurlEvent> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<java.lang.Runnable>
```

There must be some way around this. I can move to a later Java release if necessary

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

In my case this worked out to:

```
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threads, threads, 36, TimeUnit.HOURS, (BlockingQueue<Runnable>)(BlockingQueue<?>) queue);
```

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a hack. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` will store implementations of `Runnable` into this queue which are not instances of `CurlEvent`. Therefore, the queue should not have the type `BlockingQueue<CurlEvent>` in the first place.